# Java-Image not drawing to screen

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to draw an image to the screen using Java. The problem is that it does not appear and no errors occur.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GameClass extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public GameClass(){
        Timer time = new Timer(15, this);
        time.start();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void openImage(){
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("spaceship.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred!");
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Main.WW, Main.WH);
        g.drawImage(image,Main.WW/2,Main.WH/2,null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){

    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work with: `image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();`?

Comment: No, but I have to use the file name to load it, right?

Comment: No, I mean after you read it by the file name: `image = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("spaceship.png")); image = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();`

Comment: I am sorry, I am such an idiot, I forgot to call the method, it works now. Anyway, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you `openImage()` method in your constructor.

I renamed this to `loadImages()` so that this method can handle loading multiple images. I also created a static image loading function.

**Note:** If you have not already, create a `resources/` folder in your projects' `src/` folder. This folder will contain your application's assets i.e. text, image, and other data files.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*

public class GameClass extends JPanel
        implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2508183917768834794L;

    private Image image;

    // Added this, because you did not include it.
    private class Main {
        static final int WW = 256;
        static final int WH = 256;
    }

    public GameClass() {
        Timer time = new Timer(15, this);
        time.start();
        this.addKeyListener(this);
        this.setFocusable(true);

        this.loadImages();
    }

    // Load all required images into instance variables.
    public void loadImages() {
        image = loadImage("spaceship.png");
    }

    // Draw the image to the panel.
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, Main.WW, Main.WH);

        // Dimensions of spaceship
        int imgW = image.getWidth(null);
        int imgH = image.getHeight(null);

        // Dimensions of panel
        int pnlW = this.getWidth();
        int pnlH = this.getHeight();

        // Draw the spaceship in the center of the window.
        g.drawImage(image, pnlW/2 - imgW/2, pnlH/2 - imgH/2, null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { }

    // Static image loader method which utilizes the `ClassLoader`.
    public static Image loadImage(String filename) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(GameClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/" + filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading image: " + filename);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                Container panel = new GameClass();

                frame.setSize(Main.WW, Main.WH);
                frame.setTitle("Spaceship Game");
                frame.setContentPane(panel);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```